# Python code as arguments

Tags: python, arguments

How to pass a piece of code as arguments to python?

I tried like this, but it didn't work.

$ python3 'print("hello world")'

can't open file 'print(hello': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`python -c 'print("hello world")'`

Comment: I got it. I should use the escape character before '"'. Thx

Comment: @shilk: You could switch quotes `python -c "print('hello world')"` on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
python3 -c 'print("hello world")'
```